# Button Glow Removal In Dash

Tags: python, css, plotly-dash

How can i remove the shadow from all of my html.Button components when they are clicked. I have tried everything my style sheets including the following…

```html
button:focus {
  outline: 0 !important
}

button:focus {
  outline: none !important
}

button:focus {
  box-shadow: none !important
}
```

These generally work in other frameworks, but don’t seem to work in dash python. Does anyone have a solution to this?